# How do I add user downloaded header files to the list of header files that is present by default in the system?

Tags: c++, macos, gnu-make, atom-editor, header-files

I have some header files (.h and .cpp files) which I downloaded from the internet. Want to add them to the list of header files that is already there in the system by default.

I know that I can add them to the directory in which my code is present, which uses these header files. I've been doing that for most of my projects. But it is taking up a lot of unnecessary space.

I want to know if there's any way in which I can make these header files, which I downloaded from the internet as standard header files like `stdlib.h`, `iostream` etc.

**EDIT**: What I want to exactly do is this: I have downloaded [the stanford cpp library](https://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/), which has some very useful functions. I want to use them. But I don't want to copy and paste the include files in my project directory every time. Is there a way to make them as standard header files like `stdlib.h` or `iostream`? I use a Macbook. For code-editing, I use Atom. For running and compiling the program, I use the command-line -- `g++` is my compiler. I am familiar with Makefiles (GNU Make).

Comment: Does macos have the concept of `/usr/local/include` like linux? https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/please-difference-between-usr-include-and-usr-local-include-818767/

Comment: I guess this largely depends on what you're using to do the build.  CMake; VS; Makefile; commandline; xcode ....

Comment: macos does have that concept. yes. Is it fine if I just add the folder of header files to that?

Comment: @UKMonkey, I use Makefile and commandline. If it helps, I also use Atom

Comment: @AkileshKannan you want to update your question/tags with that

Comment: @UKMonkey I've updated the tags!

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles wrap other compilers;  Xcode uses clang; so I'm going to assume you're using that for now.

You want to locate your rule for generating .o objects; and add (from https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html) the argument 
`-I<dir>` as many times as required to add all your paths.

gcc is basically the same args https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++ ...`-Idir`  to impact <> and "" lookups `-iquotedir` to impact "" lookups only; and then `-Ldir` to impact link paths

Comment: I've edited my question. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @AkileshKannan there's some gcc comments too